# How do you force matlab to lift all function declarations to the top of the file before evaluating rest of the file?

Tags: matlab

I have some matlab file of form

```
result1 = func1 x y
result2 = func2 result1 x

func1 = @(x,y) ...
func2 = @(x,y) ...
```

The point here is that the function handles are declared at the bottom of the module, where it makes more sense to the project at hand. This seems to work, for a while. Then inexplicably to me, matlab throws all these `function undeclared` errors. Manually lifting all the function declaration to the top of the file, *before they're used*, solved the problem.

```
func1 = @(x,y) ...
func2 = @(x,y) ...

result1 = func1 x y
result2 = func2 result1 x
```

This is very constraining and I'd like to know if there's a way around this? Something like this would be nice:

```
var func1
var func2 

result1 = func1 x y
result2 = func2 result1 x

func1 = @(x,y) ...
func2 = @(x,y) ...
```

Such that variables are declared at top of the file though they are not bound until a  definition is found.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you're confusing anonymous function definitions and internal functions. Anonymous function handles are stored in variables, and can be used only after they are defined. Internal functions occur at the bottom of your `.m` file and are available throughout the `.m` file in which they appear. Consider `foo.m`:

```
% foo.m:
function foo(arg)
  iFoo(arg); % ok
  anonFoo(arg); % error, not defined
  anonFoo = @(x) sin(x); % defines 'anonFoo' as an anonymous function handle
  anonFoo(arg); % ok, anonFoo is defined.
end % of foo
function out = iFoo(arg)
   out = sin(arg);
end % of iFoo
% end of foo.m
```

Answer (score 0):

If you use scripts (.m-files without a `function` or `classdef` keyword at the beginning), the order of commands has to be the same as the order of commands you'd enter on the command line.

The workspace of the script is the base workspace accessible to the command line, which means that if you have previously defined the functions (for example while testing), they will be available at the beginning of the execution of the script. Executing a command like `clear all` will remove the definitions from memory, and the script fails.

If you are set on using scripts, you can create a separate script that you call from your main script. Call it `setup.m`, put the function definitions in there, and start your main script with `setup()`.

Alternatively, it could be useful to write a function (or set up a class) to have a bit more flexibility how and where you declare subfunctions/methods.